# How to disable a menuItem of a popUp button in macOS in Swift?

Tags: swift, macos, nsbutton

I'm trying to disable a menuItem of a popUp button in a macOS app. I get to set the state to on or off (the checkmark of the menu item), but I haven't found a way to set the enabled to false (greyed out).

```
func disableMyItem() {
    let myItem = actionButton.item(withTitle: "Test Item") // creating the NSMenuItem object
    myItem?.state = NSOffState // remove checkmark
    myItem?.isEnabled = false // has no effect

    print(myItem?.isEnabled) // "Optional(false)"
}
```

Comment: Does your NSMenu use auto enabling?

Comment: Possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9368654/cannot-seem-to-setenabledno-on-nsmenuitem

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Interface Builder, uncheck "Autoenables" in the Attributes Inspector.

[image: Screenshot showing exactly where that is]